# Visual Studio Code debugger for Node application stops at runMicroTasks in next_tick.js instead of in the specified breakpoint

Tags: visual-studio-code, node.js

I have a Node application that works fine when just run using npm run serve, and also when run using the Visual Studio debugger.

The only problem is that when I place breakpoints, the debugger instead of stopping at the line of code where I have the breakpoint placed, it stops in a line that is calling _runMicrotasks() in the file next_tick.js. If I have 4 breakpoints that is one after the other, then all the 4 times it stops in this same line that is calling _runMicrotaks() in the file next_tick.js instead of in the line of code where I had placed the breakpoint.

Technical Specifications: npm - 6.4.1, node - v8.12.0

[Screenshot of the debugger when it stops at _runMicrotasks()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MXrS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find the solution to my own question. What basically was happening was, by default the call stack pointed to a level deeper than the top where I had actually placed the breakpoint. So instead of taking me to the breakpoint, it took me to a level deeper in the call stack.

The solution is simply to click on the top of the call stack in the debugger view on the side(refer screenshot).

[How to make debugger go to the top of call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdEYZ.png)

Additionally for subsequent breakpoints, if the debugger always stops at the next_tick.js file, then in the call stack in the debugger menu right click on the topmost entry and click on **Toggle Skipping this File**. This ensures that the debugger does not skip the top-level file where you have placed the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

When facing with Debugger stopping at next_tick.js, add "/**" to skipFiles in launch.json
Even after that if you don't see breakpoint, open call stack drop down in the debugger menu (in vscode) and select the top most call stack entry